# What should we do with [apache-vfs], [vfs], and [apache-commons-vfs] duplicate tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

There are multiple tags related to the [Apache Commons Virtual File System](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/) library (VFS):

[vfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vfs), [apache-vfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-vfs), [apache-commons-vfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-commons-vfs)

Given that they are the same thing, should they be merged or otherwise synonymised?

Comment: Isn't there a template for this? Or is it only for burnination requests?

Comment: Burnination-only, @PeterMortensen. Although it's a neat idea to streamline other types of requests, the processes behind them are much more freeform, so there isn't much need for a template.

Answer (score 6):

[vfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vfs) appears to be meaning many other things besides; while that might mean it should be burninated, what it certainly means right now is that it shouldn't be merged with the other two.

Given the relative number of questions, making [apache-vfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-vfs) the alias for [apache-commons-vfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-commons-vfs) would seem the right approach.

Comment: According to the tag description, [tag:vfs] means "Virtual File System", and its questions are actually about this concept. E.g. Linux with its "everything is a file" actually has a concept of VFS, so combination of tags [tag:linux] and [tag:vfs] is about well-defined thing which cannot be confused with anything else.

Comment: yes, fair enough - I agree with this answer